# Delete a file from SD card if it is not in use

Tags: android, android-file

How can I detect whether a particular file is being used by some App or not. If it is not being used then I can delete it programmatically.

Suppose I am uploading a file to dropbox and meanwhile I try to delete that file from my app in that case it will be an error so, before deleting I have to check whether it is being used by some App or not.

Comment: I think the best you can do is keep track of if *you're* using the file.

Comment: you should search for implementation of junk cleaner like  something

Comment: Well you are answering your own question, if you try to delete a file in use it will give the exception so just catch the exception and proceed delete of other files.

Comment: Here error will not show at my side actually, it will show in Dropbox as the file will be deleted before completion of upload.

Comment: You saying deleting file from dropbox or sdcard? as both are different if you deleting file on dropbox then its the API which will give you the error. In any case the error will come and you can manually catch the error and do need full steps.

Comment: I am deleting the file from SD card programatically, but that file is being used by dropbox app at the same time.